# How to make my WordPress blog to offer visitors to install an Android app?

Tags: android, wordpress, popup

I have created a custom Android app for my blog and I want when someone visits the blog a notification to pop up that will say that there is an Android app for the blog and an option to install it.

I haven't yet posted the app on Google Play and only have an APK file.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple JS popup to notify the user about the download but this isn't your main problem.

By default a user will not be able to download and install an apk file quite so simply. There is a setting to prevent a user from installing apps that are not from Google Play. They would first need allow your application to be installed from their settings menu. This is done with the option: Settings >> Applications >> Unknown sources

Beyond this you would need to have the user trust that your app is not malicious and answer the question "why can you not deploy this app via Google Play as normal?"

Answer (score 0):

You can make it a download link by just putting the apk file in a shared folder in your dropbox folder (like dl.dropboxusercontent.com/....../YourApp.apk).

But still the problem that [Scott Helme](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1414715/scott-helme) told you about will exist (Users will have to admid unknows sources).

This is a solution that i used to give an app to specific people without publishing my app in the Play Store.

Hope it helps you.